# How to customize the size of the picker in appcelerator android?

Tags: css, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y2CT.png)

I am unable to fill the size of the picker in a view. i have applied the background color property for the pickerView as green. i have set the following properties for them.

**index.tss:**

```
"#pickerview":{
height:200,
left:0,
backgroundColor:"green",
right:0,
top:0,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Titanium.UI.FILL for width 
"#pickerview":{
left:0,
width:Titanium.UI.FILL,
backgroundColor:"green",
right:0,
top:0,
}

But according to iOS interface guidelines, the height must be the same size as the keyboard.

Appcelerator documentation says - On iOS, the height property is only available in iOS 9 and later. By default, the size of the picker, including its background, is fixed at the same height as the iPhone keyboard to respect the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. The default width on iOS is 320px and the height is 228px. The contents of the picker are sized to fit the picker, which may cut off text in the picker rows. Adding views to picker rows is also supported on iOS.

Comment: thanks for reaching out. it is working fine with iOS but is not working in android.